# Creating a new branch in git with zero files

Tags: git, github

I have a repository in GitHub. I have made a lot of changes in local and if I push it now, I will get a lot of conflicts. So I decided to create a new branch, but I would like this branch to look like a new repository, so that I have two different versions in git under two different branches. How do I do that?

Need some guidance on this... Sorry if it is a noob question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I believe you're looking for an orphan branch, a branch which has no parent, and helps you start a fresh set of commits not related to any other commit.

From the man page of [`git checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html):

> --orphan
>
> Create a new orphan branch, named , started from  and switch to it. The first commit made on this new
>   branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history
>   totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.
>
> The index and the working tree are adjusted as if you had previously
>   run "git checkout ". This allows you to start a new
>   history that records a set of paths similar to  by easily
>   running "git commit -a" to make the root commit.
>
> This can be useful when you want to publish the tree from a commit
>   without exposing its full history. You might want to do this to
>   publish an open source branch of a project whose current tree is
>   "clean", but whose full history contains proprietary or otherwise
>   encumbered bits of code.
>
> If you want to start a disconnected history that records a set of
>   paths that is totally different from the one of , then
>   you should clear the index and the working tree right after creating
>   the orphan branch by running "git rm -rf ." from the top level of the
>   working tree. Afterwards you will be ready to prepare your new files,
>   repopulating the working tree, by copying them from elsewhere,
>   extracting a tarball, etc.

These are the steps to achieve that:

```
git checkout --orphan my-new-orphan-branch
git rm -rf .
< Create your new files here >
git add <FILE1> <FILE2> ...
git commit -m 'Initial commit'

# Push the changes into the remote named origin
git push origin my-new-orphan-branch
```

Comment: personally i like to have my first commit be a readme and/or a gitignore file only. then you can branch from the 1st commit to a new "basically empty branch" anytime.